# Error: Program type already present: com.getcapacitor.AndroidProtocolHandler

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle, capacitor

[image]

I want to generate APK of the ionic app but I am getting

```
Program type already present: com.getcapacitor.AndroidProtocolHandler
```

error while building the ionic 4 app with angular. I have searched this on the internet and find one solution which says change

```
implementation 'ionic-team:capacitor-android:1+'
```

to

```
implementation project(':capacitor-android')"
```

in **dependencies** in **build.gradle** file but I already have **implementation project(':capacitor-android')"** in my dependency and I'm still getting the error.

This is link to the solution I have tried: https://github.com/oxylian/capacitor-facebook-login/issues/3

This is my **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.ionic.starter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url  "https://dl.bintray.com/ionic-team/capacitor"
    }
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
//    implementation 'ionic-team:capacitor-android:1+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.warn("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

This is my **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.ionic.starter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:name="io.ionic.starter.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Camera, Photos, input file -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Geolocation API -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <!-- Network API -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Navigator.getUserMedia -->
    <!-- Video -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- Audio -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: are you using any capacitor plugin?

Comment: Yes, I'm using **"capacitor-datepicker": "0.0.2"** plugin. Here is this link to the plugin : [capacitor-datepicker plugin link](https://github.com/triniwiz/capacitor-datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the date picker plugin, it has that line that you have mentioned

https://github.com/triniwiz/capacitor-datepicker/blob/master/src/android/capacitor-datepicker/build.gradle#L45

There is a pull request fixing it, but hasn’t been merged
https://github.com/triniwiz/capacitor-datepicker/pull/12